# Check if Geometry Arcpy Object has z values

Tags: arcpy, geometry, 3d, z-value

I need to know if an arcpy geometry object has z values.
I have tried without success to use the has_z attribute, since to create them you must use and I have also tried to verify if the first point of the entity has a z of None:
, however I do not like this last solution since it does not seem very robust and I think there could be cases in which the first point coincidentally has a z that is None even though the entity has 3D values. How can I check if an object has z values?

Comment: We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Can you share a sample of data where you actually have NaN for a Z value within a polyline? I can't create such a dataset, If I try to insert None of NaN for a Z value for a polyline it turns it into a zero. What data format are you generating such data from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested 3 lines: 2D, 3D with values and 3D with z values set to NULL. Espression

```
!Shape!.firstPoint.Z
```

returned NULL for 2D line only:

[image]

So, it's Ok to use z value from first point.

Comment: Hi @FelixIP, I was interested in answering this question and have seen your response above. I tried to spoof up a test featureclass with polylines that had some Z values that were NaN. I can't reset existing Z values or create a polyline in ArcMap or ArcPro where a Z value is NaN, it always resets to zero. So how did you create your LINE_3D_NULLS layer to have polylines where 1 or more Z values are NaN and not zero? Step 4 [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/edit-vertex-z-values.htm#) does not happen for me, it always goes to zero.

Comment: @Horbydd this is my point, no NULL values , it refers them to zero.  I used feature to 3d by attribute and pointed to 2 fields with Nulls as from and to Z.

Comment: First I tried has_z (property?) and also failed. Help system can be very misleading:(